# Como isolar metadados com pdfminer?

Tags: python, pdf

Escrevi esse código em Python 3 para ler os metadados de um PDF:

```
>>> from pdfminer.pdfparser import PDFParser
>>> from pdfminer.pdfdocument import PDFDocument
>>> fp = open('EMC 1-2017 PL678716 =- PL 6787-2016.pdf', 'rb')
>>> parser = PDFParser(fp)
>>> doc = PDFDocument(parser)
>>> print(doc.info)
```

E como resultado gera:

```
[{'Title': b'\xfe\xff\x00C\x00O\x00M\x00I\x00S\x00S\x00\xc3\x00O', 'Author': b'Ivanete de Araujo Costa', 'Subject': b'EMD ADI - Emenda Aditiva', 'Creator': b'\xfe\xff\x00M\x00i\x00c\x00r\x00o\x00s\x00o\x00f\x00t\x00\xae\x00 \x00W\x00o\x00r\x00d\x00 \x002\x000\x001\x000', 'CreationDate': b"D:20170314114321-07'00'", 'ModDate': b"D:20170314114321-07'00'", 'Producer': b'\xfe\xff\x00M\x00i\x00c\x00r\x00o\x00s\x00o\x00f\x00t\x00\xae\x00 \x00W\x00o\x00r\x00d\x00 \x002\x000\x001\x000'}]
```

Por favor, alguém sabe como isolar os resultados em variáveis? Por exemplo, no caso acima pegar os resultados:

```
a = "Ivanete de Araujo Costa" (campo Author)
b = "EMD ADI - Emenda Aditiva" (campo Subject)
c = "D:20170314114321-07'00" (campo CreationDate)
d = "D:20170314114321-07'00" (campo ModDate)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como você já consegue recuperar o conteúdo do pdf fica mais fácil.. essa estrutura retornada é um dicionário, onde cada chave aponta para um valor, e sua sintaxe é a seguinte:

```
dicionario.get("chave","valor_default")
```

Com base nesse exemplo vamos ao seu.

Como já possui o dicionário vamos separar em variáveis:

```
# Código anterior

#Aqui recupero o dicionário, pois ele está dentro de uma lista
dados_recuperados = doc.info[0]

#Aqui crio uma função para retornar a string literal, visto que é retornado a forma em bytes do conteúdo.
def decode_str(string):
    return string.decode("utf8")

# E por fim recupero cada chave passando ela para a função de conversão de conteúdo.
author = decode_str(dados_recuperados.get("Author"))
subject = decode_str(dados_recuperados.get("Subject"))
creation_date = decode_str(dados_recuperados.get("CreationDate"))
mod_date = decode_str(dados_recuperados.get("ModDate"))

# Fazer qualquer coisa com as variáveis.
```

Veja [aqui](https://ideone.com/YIKpEu) o script funcionando no Ideone.

Comment: Muito obrigado!
Um dos arquivos deu erro de encoding. Coloquei aqui:
https://docs.google.com/document/d/1byd6Z8hHU4CBMU9ozCSJxRNLlk55iy0_pVlFX3tp7kY/edit?usp=sharing
Infelizmente parece que tenho arquivos com encoding diferente. Sabe se há uma solução?

Comment: Seu script está em um ipython notebook público ou no github?

Comment: Está aqui https://github.com/reichaves/reftrab

Comment: Agora está no github com a mensagem de erro - UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xfe in position 0: invalid start byte